# Comparing Dates in If Statement

Tags: date, if-statement, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to compare dates in an expression. If the Closed_Date matches today's date (I am using Today()), then it would output 1 in the box, otherwise output 0. So far I have this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
=IIF(Fields!Closed_Date = Mid(Today(),1,9), "1", "0")
```

The reason I am using Mid is to just get the month, day, and year. I don't want the time included. Is there a way you can compare dates using this or another method?

Comment: Did the following answer worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Today()` actually returns today's date at midnight, so to compare your date to today you'll need to strip the time from `Closed_Date` instead. I'd recommend the `DateValue` function, since it returns date information with time set to midnight which makes for an easy comparison:

```
=IIF(DateValue(Fields!Closed_Date.Value) = Today(), "1", "0")
```

Comment: Struggled with `CDate` trying to compare a report parameter until I found this. `DateValue` Just Works.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
=IIF(
      Format(CDate(Fields!Closed_Date), "MM/dd/yyyy") = Today()
      , "1", "0"
     )
```

**OR**

```
=IIF(
      FormatDateTime(Fields!Closed_Date, DateFormat.ShortDate) = Today()
      , "1", "0"
     )
```

Avoid using string functions like `Mid` with the dates. There are lot of date related functions available in SSRS.